# How can I pass Object Details to index.html using GET or POST method and show it in HTML <pre> tags

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a socket object

```
var express = require('express');
var util = require('util');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
```

Loading index.html

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/index.html");
    })
```

For viewing what actual io  Object contains, I am using util

```
var io_ObjectDetails = util.inspect(io, {showHidden: false, depth: null});
```

The question is How can I pass io_ObjectDetails to index.html using GET or POST method and show it in HTML  tags

Comment: I found one way to pass variable to index.php. I am not sure this is correct or not.  Check this out                                                               app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send(util.inspect(io, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));
  res.sendFile(__dirname+ "/index.html");
 })

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you are trying to pass variables to a view.
The method that does that is [app.render](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.render) or [res.render](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render)

```
 app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render(__dirname+ "/index.html", io_ObjectDetails [, optional callback);
 })
```

You'll need to change your engine to render html with `res.render`. take a look at [app.engine](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.engine)